# Как не допустить повторного запуска root.after

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

есть код простейшего таймера

```
sec = Label(root, font = 'Cambria 100', text = '00:00:00',
                background = 'Gray',
                foreground = 'Red')
def tick():
  global temp, after_id
  after_id = root.after (1000, tick)
  f_temp = dt.utcfromtimestamp (temp).strftime ('%H:%M:%S')
  sec.configure (text=(str (f_temp)))
  temp += 1
```

и функций и кнопок его запуска

```
   def post1_ON():
      """тут размещаются какието надписи и т.д не важно"""
      tick()
      
    def post2_ON():
      """тут размещаются какието другие надписи и т.д не важно"""
      tick()
    
    
       post_1 = Button(root,
                         text='*******',
                         font='Cambria 14',
                         bg='Gainsboro',
                         foreground='Black',
                          command= post1_ON
                         )
        post_1.place(x=10, y=950)
    
        post_2 = Button(root,
                                 text='********',
                                 font='Cambria 14',
                                 bg='Gainsboro',
                                 foreground='Black',
                                 command=post2_ON
                                 )
        post_2.place(x=160, y=950)
```

---

Итак вопрос проблема: при нажатии на кпопку повторно таймер ускоряется,

если добавить перед вызом tick()  root.after_cancel(after_id), то таймер останавливается
и заново не запускается появляется ошибка
*ValueError: id must be a valid identifier returned from after or after_idle*
Уровень моих знаний 0.1 и google не помог.  **Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопок таймер
продолжал работать без ускорений**.

---

P.S. кнопки должны отображаться всегда, нажимать их можно в любом порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай глобальную переменную boll
чтобы получилось что-то типо:

```
flag = True
```

```
def post1_ON():
    global flag
    if flag == True: 
        flag = False
        tick()
        """тут размещаются какието надписи и т.д не важно"""
      
def post2_ON():
    global flag
    if flag == True: 
        flag = False
        tick()
        """тут размещаются какието надписи и т.д не важно"""
```

По идеи должно заработать

что-бы была возможность выключить таймер и включить повторно можно попробовать добавить вторую бул переменную и проверку в его код

Comment: дополню что такую проверку лучше делать сразу и если не вышло то делать возврат. чтобы не делать все расчёты и какието надписи

Comment: спасибо тупанул все гениальное просто. написал доп функцию tick_check c проверкой и уже на кнопках запускаю её

Comment: я соглашусь и с insolor я забыл про global, и с Интик это верно